# Javascript replace function for adding mark tag around string in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a editable paragraph. I want to mark some words in this paragraph. This words determine by a JSON response that is returned from another page. format of the response is something like bellow.

HTML:

```
<p id="area" contenteditable>

</p>
<button class="btn dark" id="send">Send</button>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").click(function() {
        var d = $("#area").text();
        $.post("responser.php", { str : d})
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            var words = obj.words;
            $.each( words, function( key, value ) {
                console.log(value.inLex);
                if(!value.inLex) {
                    d = d.replace(value.word, "<mark>"+value.word+"</mark>");
                }
            });
            $("#area").text(d);
        })
    });
});
```

JSON Response:

```
{"words":[
    {"key":0,"word":"hello","inLex":false},
    {"key":1,"word":"man","inLex":true},
    {"key":2,"word":"how","inLex":false},
    {"key":3,"word":"are","inLex":true},
    {"key":4,"word":"you","inLex":false},
    {"key":5,"word":"","inLex":true}
]}
```

The problem is that **replace** function acts unlike my expectation and shows HTML tags like text, something like bellow.
[image]

Comment: `.text()` is to render a value as text, use `html()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$().text()` sets the content of the text node inside of the element.

What you are looking for is `$().html()` which sets the innerHTML of the element.

Try replacing `$("#area").text(d);` with `$("#area").html(d);`